# Travel before submission of UK visit visa application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am about to submit my application for a UK visit visa in Pakistan where I intend to go for a family visit either end of March or in April. However, I have a travel (tourism purpose) scheduled for the first two weeks of March. This was pre-booked and I am doing it as some of my leaves will lapse mid-March. I have two questions:

1. If I submit my application but have not received my passport back from the UK visa centre in time, can I ask for my passport back without withdrawing the application? I will need my passport for travel.
2. If I submit the application at the end of February (just before travelling), and schedule my appointment with the visa centre two weeks later (after my travel) as it generally takes 1-2 weeks to get an appointment, how do I disclose that country as part of my travel history? I will not have travelled yet, but by the time I hand in my passport that country's stamps/visa will be on it. Will they look at at as a deception, considering that at the time of my application submission, I had not travelled to that country.

Any other suggestion in this situation would be welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I've been in the same situation just a few weeks ago.

I dismissed option 1 (as described in your question) because one needs to withdraw the application to get the passport back.

I went with the option 2 (to schedule the appointment right after my travel) and mentioned the details of my upcoming trip in the "additional information" section of the application.

Comment: There is a 3rd option. Pay a little extra and avail ‘keep your passport’ value added service.

Comment: @HankyPanky that sounds great but this option isn't available at every application center. Maybe the OP is in luck, tho.